# Symbolic vector norm with indexed variables

Tags: python, sympy

I'd like to express a vector norm of the difference of two indexed variables. In mathematical notation what I'm after is:

```
|| x_a - y_b ||
```

Where `x` and `y` are sets of points in some space. In Sympy I've managed to create the variables:

```
x = sp.IndexedBase('x')
a = sp.Idx('a')
y = sp.IndexedBase('y')
b = sp.Idx('b')
```

And express a simple difference:

```
diff = (x[a] - y[b])
```

But how could I express the norm? It seems that every reference I've found to calculating norms leads to matrices. The variables indeed represent vectors, but I don't really care about the dimensionality.

Are there indexed matrices, should I use matrix columns and just choose a dimensionality, or is there some other way of formulating a norm?

---

EDIT:

I made some progress and tried to do it using another index common to both vectors, i.e. the supposed dimensionality.

```
N, D = sp.symbols('N D', integer=True)
d = sp.Idx('d', D)

x = sp.IndexedBase('x')
a = sp.Idx('a', N)
y = sp.IndexedBase('y')
b = sp.Idx('b', N)
norm = sp.sqrt(sp.Sum((x[a, d] - y[b, d]) ** 2, (d, 0, D - 1)))
```

This works indeed, but what I can't do is then e.g. differentiate with respect to the reduced index `x[a]`. In my mind the `d` index should be reduced in that expression, especially because the dimensionality is defined and the summation is done over the full range. Am I still missing something?